# Magento Search System Issue

Tags: catalogsearch, magento2.2.6

I`m having a strange issue with catalog searching.

Performing this simple search returns 35 products :

```
catalogsearch/result/index/?q=bac
```

However, when I refine it by category, I still receive the same number of products including products from other categories

i.e. search :

```
/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=3&q=bac
```

This is all with the default magento products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with algolia search

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140222)

Comment: Yes i know, but it saves people answering.  When it is fixed I will update